# File.Create Throwing IOException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ioexception

I have a program that employs a simple logging process.  The idea is that every day a new file gets created that corresponds with the date unless the file already exists, in which case it's just appended to.  The problem is, File.Create is throwing an error every time it runs.  I found a solution to the problem that says File.Create is opening a FileStream and you just need to call it with a .close(); but that solution didn't work for me, I'm still getting the IO exception saying that the file is in use by another process, which is impossible since it doesn't exist until File.Create creates it, and nothing else uses these files.
Here's the code:

```
public static void logResults(System.Reflection.MethodBase method, Results result, string message)
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        int index = date.IndexOf(" ");
        string subString = date.Substring(0, index);
        string nwDate = Regex.Replace(subString, "/", "");
        logFileName = "WebsiteRegressionProduction_TestCycle." + nwDate;
        string currentLogFile = logFileLocation + @"\" + logFileName;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (!File.Exists(currentLogFile))
        {

            File.Create(currentLogFile).Close();
            sb.Append("DATE-TIME\tACTION\tTEST CLASS\tTEST NAME\tTEST STATUS\tERROR MESSAGES");
            sb.Append("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            string previousLogs = File.ReadAllText(currentLogFile);
            sb.Append(previousLogs);
        }
        sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        sb.Append(" : ");
        sb.Append("Text Executed: ");
        sb.Append(method.ReflectedType.Name + " : ");
        sb.Append(method + " : ");
        sb.Append(result.ToString());
        sb.Append(" : ");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("\n");

        File.WriteAllText(currentLogFile, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I have run your code and I cannot see a problem with the file access. On what line is the exception occuring?

Comment: It's happening right at the File.Create line.  
File.Create(currentLogFile);     or
File.Create(currentLogFile).Close();
Both throw:
IOException was unhandled by user code
The process cannot acces the file "<path>" because it is being used by another process

Comment: Are you certain that the currentLogFile path is correct? I have your code and it should work just fine provided the path is valid. Does the exception method give you any more information?

Comment: No information other than the 'because it is being used by another process'.  The path is definitely correct; if the file is manually created, then the

    if(!File.Exists(currentLogFile))
skips because the code finds the file, which couldn't happen if the path wasn't correct

Answer (score 1):

[File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) is probably a much better option for what you are trying to accomplish.  It will create the file if it is missing and add the text to the end.  If you want to add the header to the start of the file, you'll just have to do a quick manual check to see if the file exists first.

Answer (score 1):

Using suggestions from the answers, I've changed my code.  It doesn't throw an exception anymore when first creating the file, but I'll mark an answer as Accepted when someone can explain why File.Create was throwing an IOException saying that the file was already in use and could not be accessed.

```
        public static void logResults(System.Reflection.MethodBase method, Results result, string message)
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        int index = date.IndexOf(" ");
        string subString = date.Substring(0, index);
        string nwDate = Regex.Replace(subString, "/", "");
        logFileName = "WebsiteRegressionProduction_TestCycle." + nwDate;
        string currentLogFile = logFileLocation + @"\" + logFileName;
        if (!File.Exists(currentLogFile))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(currentLogFile,
                "DATE-TIME\tACTION\tTEST CLASS\tTEST NAME\tTEST STATUS\tERROR MESSAGES\n\n", Encoding.ASCII);
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0} : Test Executed: {1} : {2} : {3}\n\n", DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            method.ReflectedType.Name, method, message));
        using (var stream = File.AppendText(currentLogFile))
        {
            stream.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is actually still throwing an error, but only on the machine that is executing the program; if I run it locally, no error even though the path remains the same...

Comment: It sounds like you are hitting a permissions issue:  does the user executing the program have write access?  Try running as administrator?

Also, I'd recommend you initialize your stringbuilder earlier, and simply do a sb.Append(yourHeaderText) instead of writing to the file twice.

Answer (score 0):

1) Why do you read all previous content to append?
2) You can simply use log4net that do all that work for "free"

However, I suggest you to use a stream to have more control over the operation

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append);
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The string you wanna append");
            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
```

The FileMode.Append open the specified (filePath) in Append if exists or create it if not.

Answer (score 0):

File.Create returns FileStream, so you should be using a FileStream object like so:

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(currentLogFile);
```

Then do all your read/writes with the fs object.

Comment: The same error is thrown when I implement your changes.

    FileStream fs = File.Create(currentLogFile);
IOException was unhandled by user code
The process cannot acces the file '\\testfiler\data\files\logFiles\WebsiteRegressionProduction_TestCycle.8202013' because it is being used by another process

Comment: If I had to venture a guess. Possibly Visual Studio had a temp file created somewhere that was the handle to your newly created file and was the process that was actually locking the file.  I noticed that in your original code, your never close the file.  As a side note, WriteAllText actually does all three file operations in a single command (Create, Write, Close).  I'm just spitballing here as I don't have access to Visual Studio right now.